# Why does the cached entities suddenly jump?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, caching, lambda

I have :

```
var c = cboCustomer.SelectedItem as Customer;
var t = cboTrailer.SelectedItem as Trailer;
using (var db = new CAPSContainer())
{
   db.Attach(c); --> Tracker has now 1 entity
   db.Attach(t); --> Tracker has now 2 entities
   c.Trailers.Remove(t); --> Tracker has now 29! entities loaded
   db.DeleteObject(t);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am trying to understand how this loading / caching is working because I am having some other issues related to it, any ideas why the cached amount suddenly jumps?

I am using EF 5.0.

Comment: Possibly because it loaded Trailers in order to remove a trailer.

Comment: @JustinHarvey why would it do that, and why 29?

Comment: Its difficult to know without more on what version of EF you are using and whether code or model first etc.

Comment: Customer SelectedItem already exists in your database? How much Trailers it has?

Comment: @Boomer 28 :) so now we know why its 29. But why does it load all them into the cache/object manager when I just want to remove the one?

Comment: because when you said `c.Trailers`, that tells the dbcontext to load all the Trailers from the database, as @JustinHarvey said

Comment: @Boomer why do I have to remove a trailer with .Remove(t) then also delete it using DeleteObject(t)? in a DB I would just have to remove the trailer row...

Comment: I believe the `DeleteObject` is enough

Comment: @Boomer I cannot, but that is for another Q : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761004/why-can-i-not-delete-an-entity-with-just-deleteobjecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default configuration probably had LazyLoadingEnabled set.  So child lists won't get loaded until they are accessed, see this article for a more detailed explanation:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

By the way, if you just want to remove one without loading the lot, then you can use DeleteObject as Boomer said.